# Finding nearest street given a lat-long location

Tags: location, latitude-longitude, openstreetmap

Is there any such API where given a location (in terms of latlong), I could find whether the given point is on road/street or not. And if possible also gives me nearest street/road to that location. I found API from [Find nearby Streets] ->  http://www.geonames.org/maps/us-reverse-geocoder.html#findNearbyStreets , but it just gives solution for US. 
Help me if u know of any better solution/algorithm. ( I am particularly interested in India.)

Comment: Also is there any API to plot such points on nearest road location?. For drawing complete rote on road

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Google Maps Geocoding API which does exactly that: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Take a look at the "Reverse Geocoding" section.

Answer (score 5):

Google maps api provides reverse Geocoding api, you need to pass lat and long values to get address

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false
```

Check this
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON

Comment: Thank You Sandeep and Mathias. Could any of you tell me if there is a way by which I can know that the given lat long lies on a road or not. Basically I want to eliminate points which are not on street in my app, i.e. if anybody is using my app sitting at home, I do not want that lat long to be stored.

Comment: Is there any way to plot such points on nearest road's lat long?

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler with OSRM (nearest) webservice. Look at my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30403046/4640499